# Linux SPI read and write may occasionally be slow?

Tags: arm, linux-device-driver, spi

I am testing the read and write speed of `SPI`, and I am using the Linux kernel v3.10. The following IOCTL driver code is from Linux kernel v3.10, and I only added a few lines of printing. I have found through `dmesg` that occasionally the execution time from enter IOCTL to the end can be very long, usually around `500 us`, and occasionally around `3ms`(as printed in the `dmesg` section below). May I ask the reason for this difference and what is the general reason?

My processor is `A40i`, and its architecture is `ARM v7`.In my system, there is only one process that reads and writes to this `SPI` interface.

A part of `dmesg`:

```auto
[73365.845761] enter ioctl
[73365.845775] add lock
[73365.848729] write end
[73365.848744] end ioctl
```

SPI driver code:

```c
static long
spidev_ioctl(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
        int                     err = 0;
        int                     retval = 0;
        struct spidev_data      *spidev;
        struct spi_device       *spi;
        u32                     tmp;
        unsigned                n_ioc;
        struct spi_ioc_transfer *ioc;
        printk("enter ioctl\n");
        /* Check type and command number */
        if (_IOC_TYPE(cmd) != SPI_IOC_MAGIC)
                return -ENOTTY;

        /* Check access direction once here; don't repeat below.
         * IOC_DIR is from the user perspective, while access_ok is
         * from the kernel perspective; so they look reversed.
         */
        if (_IOC_DIR(cmd) & _IOC_READ)
                err = !access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE,
                                (void __user *)arg, _IOC_SIZE(cmd));
        if (err == 0 && _IOC_DIR(cmd) & _IOC_WRITE)
                err = !access_ok(VERIFY_READ,
                                (void __user *)arg, _IOC_SIZE(cmd));
        if (err)
                return -EFAULT;

        /* guard against device removal before, or while,
         * we issue this ioctl.
         */
        spidev = filp->private_data;
        spin_lock_irq(&spidev->spi_lock);
        spi = spi_dev_get(spidev->spi);
        spin_unlock_irq(&spidev->spi_lock);

        if (spi == NULL)
                return -ESHUTDOWN;

        /* use the buffer lock here for triple duty:
         *  - prevent I/O (from us) so calling spi_setup() is safe;
         *  - prevent concurrent SPI_IOC_WR_* from morphing
         *    data fields while SPI_IOC_RD_* reads them;
         *  - SPI_IOC_MESSAGE needs the buffer locked "normally".
         */

        printk("add lock\n");
        mutex_lock(&spidev->buf_lock);

        switch (cmd) {
        /* read requests */
        case SPI_IOC_RD_MODE:
                retval = __put_user(spi->mode & SPI_MODE_MASK,
                                        (__u8 __user *)arg);
                break;
        case SPI_IOC_RD_LSB_FIRST:
                retval = __put_user((spi->mode & SPI_LSB_FIRST) ?  1 : 0,
                                        (__u8 __user *)arg);
                break;
        case SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD:
                retval = __put_user(spi->bits_per_word, (__u8 __user *)arg);
                break;
        case SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ:
                retval = __put_user(spi->max_speed_hz, (__u32 __user *)arg);
                break;
        /* write requests */
        case SPI_IOC_WR_MODE:
                retval = __get_user(tmp, (u8 __user *)arg);
                if (retval == 0) {
                        u8      save = spi->mode;

                        if (tmp & ~SPI_MODE_MASK) {
                                retval = -EINVAL;
                                break;
                        }

                        tmp |= spi->mode & ~SPI_MODE_MASK;
                        spi->mode = (u8)tmp;
                        retval = spi_setup(spi);
                        if (retval < 0)
                                spi->mode = save;
                        else
                                dev_dbg(&spi->dev, "spi mode %02x\n", tmp);
                }
                break;
        case SPI_IOC_WR_LSB_FIRST:
                retval = __get_user(tmp, (__u8 __user *)arg);
                if (retval == 0) {
                        u8      save = spi->mode;

                        if (tmp)
                                spi->mode |= SPI_LSB_FIRST;
                        else
                                spi->mode &= ~SPI_LSB_FIRST;
                        retval = spi_setup(spi);
                        if (retval < 0)
                                spi->mode = save;
                        else
                                dev_dbg(&spi->dev, "%csb first\n",
                                                tmp ? 'l' : 'm');
                }
                break;
        case SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD:
                retval = __get_user(tmp, (__u8 __user *)arg);
                if (retval == 0) {
                        u8      save = spi->bits_per_word;

                        spi->bits_per_word = tmp;
                        retval = spi_setup(spi);
                        if (retval < 0)
                                spi->bits_per_word = save;
                        else
                                dev_dbg(&spi->dev, "%d bits per word\n", tmp);
                }
                break;
        case SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ:
                retval = __get_user(tmp, (__u32 __user *)arg);
                if (retval == 0) {
                        u32     save = spi->max_speed_hz;

                        spi->max_speed_hz = tmp;
                        retval = spi_setup(spi);
                        if (retval < 0)
                                spi->max_speed_hz = save;
                        else
                                dev_dbg(&spi->dev, "%d Hz (max)\n", tmp);
                }
                break;

        default:
                /* segmented and/or full-duplex I/O request */
                if (_IOC_NR(cmd) != _IOC_NR(SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(0))
                                || _IOC_DIR(cmd) != _IOC_WRITE) {
                        retval = -ENOTTY;
                        break;
                }

                tmp = _IOC_SIZE(cmd);
                if ((tmp % sizeof(struct spi_ioc_transfer)) != 0) {
                        retval = -EINVAL;
                        break;
                }
                n_ioc = tmp / sizeof(struct spi_ioc_transfer);
                if (n_ioc == 0)
                        break;

                /* copy into scratch area */
                ioc = kmalloc(tmp, GFP_KERNEL);
                if (!ioc) {
                        retval = -ENOMEM;
                        break;
                }
                if (__copy_from_user(ioc, (void __user *)arg, tmp)) {
                        kfree(ioc);
                        retval = -EFAULT;
                        break;
                }

                /* translate to spi_message, execute */
                retval = spidev_message(spidev, ioc, n_ioc);
                kfree(ioc);
                break;
        }

        mutex_unlock(&spidev->buf_lock);
        printk("write end\n");
        spi_dev_put(spi);
        printk("end ioctl\n");
        return retval;
}
```

Comment: Are there any other devices on the same SPI bus (i.e. sharing the MISO and MOSI lines with the spidev device)? You could add more `printk` calls to narrow down the location of the delay.

Comment: I recommend you to read the SPI protocol documentation to undestand the terms _transfer_, _message_, _chip select_, and then update your question with more clarification. Voting to close this one.